# R fucntion to sum up two binary variables or transform the variables in away that allows for addition?

Tags: r, binary, sum

I have a dataset with multiple risk facktors for humans and want to see which participants present with multiple risk factors.

I have created categories such as the presence of high blood pressure (1= yes, 0=no) and overweight BMI (1= yes, 0=no) e.g.,

```
df$BP_above <- ifelse(df$BP >= 130,
                                c("1"), c("0")) #1 is above cut-off
```

I have tried to sum these two variables hoping that I will get values that are either 0, 1 or 2.
Sum <- df$BP_above + df$overweight

but get the error message: non-numeric argument to binary operator
I have tried the below to change into numeric variables but got the same error message.

```
as.numeric(as.numeric(df$BP_above))
transform(df, BP_above = as.numeric(BP_above))
transform(dfo_Imputed, TG_above = as.numeric(TG_above))
```

I have seen others ask similar but more complex questions (with quite complex solutions) that I unfortuntely cant make work on my data set.

Thanks in advance for helping out!

Comment: `df$BP_above <- as.integer(df$BP >= 130)`

Answer (score 1):

You assigned characters "1" and "0". Assign numerics instead:

```r
df$BP_above <- ifelse(df$BP >= 130, 1, 0)
```

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please accept an answer.